# How to make function 'extensible' in C?

Tags: c, math

I have the following function, which should work fine with a for loop to analyze whether or not the series of double results have "stabilized".  What I have written analyzes 3 points total and I'm wondering how I could take in a variable called "minNumberOfSamples" and have it compare that many results?

```
    bool MeasurementStabilized(double newResult, double percentageThreshold, double limitRange)
{
    static double meas1 = 1E100;
    static double meas2 = 1E100;

    if ((abs(newResult - meas2) / limitRange >= percentageThreshold) ||
        (abs(meas2 - meas1) / limitRange >= percentageThreshold))
        return TRUE;

    meas1 = meas2;
    meas2 = newResult;
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Rather than having two hard-wired static variables to the last two inputs, you could have a static array with a fixed capacity which is large enough to handle the sort of values for `minNumberOfSamples` that you expect to encounter .

Comment: How could one loop through all the array variables instead of the if statement then?

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm close now with the help from @John Coleman.  This seems to do the job but looking for some improvements if any one can think of any:

```
static double* gArr;

void MeasurementStabilizedCleanup(void)
{
    free(gArr); 
}

static bool MeasurementStabilized(double newResult, double percentageThreshold, double limitRange, int minNumberOfSamples)
{
    static bool firstRun = TRUE;
    bool retVal = TRUE;
    int x;

    //init variables
    if (firstRun)
    {
        gArr = malloc((minNumberOfSamples + 1) * sizeof(double)); 
        for(x = 0; x <= minNumberOfSamples; x++)
        {
            gArr[x] = 1E100;
        }
        firstRun = FALSE;
    }

    //loop through each value comparing it to the latest result
    for(x = minNumberOfSamples - 1; x >= 0; x--)
    {
        gArr[x + 1] = gArr[x];  //4 -> 5 , 3 -> 4, ...
        if (fabs(newResult - gArr[x]) / limitRange >= percentageThreshold)
            retVal = FALSE;
    }
    gArr[0] = newResult;    //dont forget to update the latest sample   
    return retVal;  
}

void main(void)
{
    double doubles[] = {1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4};
    int x;

    for (x = 0; x <= 6; x++)
    {
        if(MeasurementStabilized(doubles[x], 0.01, 4, 4))
        {
            ;
        }
    }
    MeasurementStabilizedCleanup();
}
```

Comment: you always overwrite the latest result with `meas[x] = meas[x - 1];` so the latest result will always be equal to the oldest one. And you should use `if (abs(newResult - meas[x]) >= percentageThreshold*limitRange)` instead